# How can I make my cards a certain size without overflowing?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently working on a small landing page, I'm making a card component for property displaying.
I think the cards I am building look too big for bigger screens and I want to make them a certain size so it doesn't look that big, so I set a max-height property in my CSS, but the content of the card overflows from it.

How can I make the content flow with the sizing of the box?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8offG.png

Here's the markup for cards

```
 <div class="card_container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/anuncio3.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/anuncio3.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/anuncio3.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, quibusdam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/header.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, quibusdam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

And here's the CSS

```css
    .card_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5rem;
    justify-content: center;
}


.card{
    display: flex;
    width: 35rem;
    max-height: 60rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: .5rem;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:space-evenly;
    
        li{
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            color: rgb(52, 52, 54);
        }
    
    }
   
}

.card_header{
 
    img{
        
        border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

.card_body{
   

    .property_description{
        margin:1rem;
        
    }
}


.card_footer{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
   
   
}

.price{
    font-size: 2rem;
 
}
```

Comment: You not using plain CSS. Please add the correct tag such as SCSS, LESS, SASS... As [repro] it would be better if you include a compiled version of it so it would be plain CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Added the `max-height` and the `overflow-y: scroll` to the `.card_body` so it won't overflow. Also the `css` you have provided is full of with mistakes. I have replaced the wrongly placed `{}` and removed some unnecessary `</i>` tags from your HTML.

```css
.card_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card{
    display: flex;
    width: 15rem;
    max-height: 60rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.card_body {
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* -ms-overflow-style: none; scrollbar-width: none; Hide scrollbar if you want */
} /*.card_body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } */
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
li{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: rgb(52, 52, 54);
}
```

```html
 <div class="card_container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/anuncio3.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/anuncio3.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/anuncio3.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, quibusdam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_header">
                <img src="/build/img/header.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card_body">

                <h2 class="mt-0 mb-0">Lakeside Cottage</h2>

                <div class="tags">
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Forest</span>
                    <span class="tag tag-red">Pool</span>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i></li>
                    <li>3 <i class="fa-solid fa-toilet"></i></li>
                    <li>4 <i class="fa-solid fa-car"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="property_description ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, quibusdam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, odio?</p>
                <span class="price" style="display:block ;">$USD 120.000</span>

            </div>
            <div class="card_footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-red">See more details</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: I see! I forgot to add that i am using SASS for my CSS preprocessor. Since SASS supports nesting i am no longer required to use standard CSS brackets, thanks for the support!